# Converting XML to JSON using Ballerina with XSD schema

Tags: xml, xsd, ballerina

I need help on converting XML to JSON manually using XSD schema, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Currently Ballerina does not support XSD validations. You can use following code sample to covert a json to xml without schema validations.

```
json j1 = {
        "Store": {
            "@id": "AST",
            "name": "Anne",
            "address": {
                "street": "Main",
                "city": "94"
            },
            "codes": ["4", "8"]
        }
    };

var x1 = xmldata:fromJson(j1);
```

Above code was taken from following Ballerina example

https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/json-to-xml-conversion.html